# from linux to windows usb camera connection

Tags: ros, image, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody
I have ROS fuerte running on a robot (on which I have a ptz ethernet camera and a usb logitech camera). The robot is running on linux ubuntu oneiric (11.10). What I was wondering and I need your expert help on is this:
I can connect over wifi from a windows 7 machine to my robot. I can see from a web broswer the image coming from the PTZ ethernet camera. How can I connect and see the image coming from the usb logitech camera? On linux, when I run the command rosrun image_view image_view image:=/logitech_usb_cam/image_raw I can see the image. But how do I do that from a windows machine? Any ideas?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54866/from-linux-to-windows-usb-camera-connection/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-10**:
Are you running ROS on the windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run the [mjpeg_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mjpeg_server) on the robot, and connect a browser to the url stream that you'd like to view. You have not clarified if the windows machine is running ROS, so there may be other possibilities that could exist for you.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0